# what this parameters do end what i need put on them in blockchain ver2

Tags: blockchain, block, altcoin-development, bip

```
/** What block version to use for new blocks (pre versionbits) */
static const int32_t VERSIONBITS_LAST_OLD_BLOCK_VERSION = 4;
/** What bits to set in version for versionbits blocks */
static const int32_t VERSIONBITS_TOP_BITS = 0x20000000UL;
/** What bitmask determines whether versionbits is in use */
static const int32_t VERSIONBITS_TOP_MASK = 0xE0000000UL;
/** Total bits available for versionbits */
static const int32_t VERSIONBITS_NUM_BITS = 29;
```

bip's 65 end 66 are on 3 end 4 version block's. But blockchain latest block is 2 version. What value i need put on this for upgrade when new block's be mined to ver 3 end 4.

or i need change the bip 65 end 66 to the same block ver4, end put value prev block to 2 ? How it do correctly

Comment: uh, four downvotes without explanation... could someone explain? I see that tseries is new here, trying to read and understand the code, and get involved, shouldn't this merit some understanding? Even if english seems not to be native language (same with me). @tseries: I feel the question is not precise enough, so people find it difficult to help out. You might explain a bit more, what you intend to do. BIP66 is "Strict DER signatures" and BIP65 is "OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY" - at least for bitcoin world... difficult to see, how this relates to blockchain version code you mention.

Comment: The downvotes are likely because the question is unclear as to what the question actually is.

Answer (score 0):

```
static const int32_t VERSIONBITS_LAST_OLD_BLOCK_VERSION = 4;
```

no need for change, for old blockchain need add in

```
consensus.BIP65Height = 4; //  Block with what start bip if it's old block chain need add block 1,2,3 next block after block chain ( for people update before the this block can be mined. 
consensus.BIP66Height = 14; // this to, but + count off blocks in nMinerconfirmationwindow.

consensus.nRuleChangeActivationThreshold = 6; // 75% of 8064
consensus.nMinerConfirmationWindow = 8; //
```

End bip's be activated after this count of block be mined.

end you cant answer this simple question ?